# Windows 10 breaks after I enable WSL

Tags: windows, windows-10

I create recovery point in Windows before doing this, so this is the only way I can revert this and fix it.
What is the problem?

1. I enable WSL in Windows Features
2. Restarting my laptop

Now I have this problems: I cannot open poweshell, it says mscoree.dll is missing. And nothing can fix this. I tried copying this file from another computer and this won't help, powershell silently collapses just after I open it. Also gpedit.msc is broken and not working too. And when I am open Windows Features to disable WSL - it's empty now. Just an empty window with no feature list at all. And no, launching Windows Module Installer service would not help. It remains empty.
The only thing that helps me is reverting to recovery point before enabling WSL.

So. Why this happens and how to enable WSL without breaking my Windows?

Comment: What comment? Did you had any solution?

Comment: OK, since you're asking, but first **DISCLAIMER**: according to @Ramhound, whose knowledge of Windows vastly exceeds mine, while this MS Answers posting is for Win10/11, the offered solution isn't valid because 1) .NET 3.5 coming with Win10/11 can't be reinstalled and 2) WSL2 coming with Win10/11 doesn't require .NET 3.5 anyway. So no guarantees. Here's the posting anyway: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/mscoreedll-file-missing/c86211d9-7999-4683-93f9-469dc4def060

Comment: oh, thank you!!!

Comment: Did the MS advice help you resolve the issue? If yes, you should [write a proper answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) with explanation what you did, and after 48 hours return to [accept](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer) it. That way this might be helpful to others experiencing similar issue.